# document.getElementById doesn't work despite window onload

Tags: javascript, html

I have a small section of code that gets the URL of the page, and fills a `textarea` with id `token-box` with all the content after a `#` character.

I originally had the javascript after the `<p>` tag. That didn't work, and neither does the `window.onload` function.

```
<p id="token">

  <script>

  window.onload = function() {
    var url = location.href
    var index = url.search(/access_token=/g)
    var access_token = url.substring(index+13,index+37)
    if (index > 18) {
      document.getElementById("token-description").value = "Your access token is:<br>";
      document.getElementById("token-box").value = access_token;
    }
    document.getElementById("token-box").select();
  }

  </script>

  <p id="token-description" class="token-title" value="hello">
  </p>

  <input id="token-box" type="text" name="token" value="lol">
</p>
```

What is really strange is that the javascript that fills the `input` (the second `document.getElementById` does work. Why can I not fill the value of my `<p>` tag?

Comment: By the way, you can't place one `p` inside of other `p`.

Comment: @Qwertiy Nice to know :) Should I use span?

Comment: You should use block-element like `div`. Anyway, there are few elements which will be auto-closed and `p` is one of them, when `span` isn't. https://jsfiddle.net/qwd9j26x/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no `value` for a `P` element.

Change

```
document.getElementById("token-description").value = "Your access token is:<br>";
```

to

```
document.getElementById("token-description").innerHTML = "Your access token is:<br>";
```